# Ruby function returning true rather than false when using a break in a function that checks for bots

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, bots, break

I have a function that is supposed to return a boolean. Inside the function I am checking to see if the user is cookied. If the user has not been cookied than I want to run a check to see if they are a bot. I have an array called @bots conatining strings like 'googlebot' and 'msnbot' and so on. The @bots array is created with a before_filter and is available.

What I want to do is allow bots access even if they are not cookied. For some reason this is not working as I need it too. I am fairly new to RoR and I appreciate any and all help that can be offered. Thanks in advance.

I am using chrome for testing so I added "Chrome" to the bots array and deleted my cookie but the function is still returning false. I am sure I am overlooking something.

```
def verified?
  if cookies[:verified].nil? 
    @bots.each do |bot| 
      if request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].include? bot
        true
        break
      else
        false
      end
    end
  else
    true
  end 
end
```

Comment: you have two true, which one is returned,not getting that. so do add some message with each `true`,which would help for debugging.

Answer (score 3):

This function can be greatly simplified. Try something like this:

```
def verified?
  cookies[:verified].present? or @bots.any? do |bot|
    request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].include? bot
  end
end
```

[Here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) are the docs for the `any?` function, which does exactly what you're looking for here. It's better to use built in functions like this so your code is clearer and less prone to errors than when you reimplement such functions yourself.